# Terminology for functions whose slopes have the same sign?

Tags: terminology

Given functions `F` and `G`, where the slope of `F` has the same sign as the slope of `G`. What is the correct terminology for the relationship between these two functions?

Note that there might not be a constant multiple factor that maps the slope of one to the other.

Comment: In the title you wrote that the slopes have the same sign. In the body you wrote that the slopes have the same increasing/decreasing property. These are not the same. You might want to clarify it.

Comment: @user251257 Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Not every phenomenon has a name already attached to it. You should feel free to give it your own name, which is not saying that I suggest that you name it after yourself.

Comment: if I understood correctly the functions have the same derivative, when a derivative can be defined at a point, so (if I dont miss something) the functions are equal up to a constant for each differentiable piece. As far as I know there is no a name for that.